# How can I use Array.filter() to return items in blocks of 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider this array:

```
var items = [
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2',
  'Item 3',
  'Item 4',
  'Item 5',
  'Item 6',
  'Item 7',
  'Item 8',
  'Item 9',
  'Item 10',
];
```

I am trying to work out, how I can filter an array, so that I can return something like the following in chunks of 2:

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 5, Item 6, Item 9, Item 10
```

I should grab 2 items, skip 2 items and repeat.

I tried using `Array.map()` for this job, but I'm failing to understand what logic I'd need to achieve this effect.

```
console.clear();

var items = [
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2',
  'Item 3',
  'Item 4',
  'Item 5',
  'Item 6',
  'Item 7',
  'Item 8',
  'Item 9',
  'Item 10',
];

var selected = items.filter(function(item, index) {
  return index % 2; // Obviously not what I want.
});

console.log(selected);
```

Any help or guidence would be much appreciated.

NB: I did actually solve this using 2 different arrays, but I'd like to try solving it in one solidified solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you look at the pattern, It shows that you want to select the elements which are completely divisible by four and next of that.

```
0  1
4  5
8  9
12 13
16 17
...
```

Use `filter` with `index` whose remainder after division by 4 is 0 or 1.

i.e. use

```
return (index % 4) < 2;
```

**Demo**

```js
var items = [
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2',
  'Item 3',
  'Item 4',
  'Item 5',
  'Item 6',
  'Item 7',
  'Item 8',
  'Item 9',
  'Item 10',
];

var filtered = items.filter(function(e, index) {
  return (index % 4) < 2;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Was about to post pretty much the same, but with `return (index % 4) < 2;`, the OP wanting the first two of each set of four items.

Comment: Tushar - you God damn genius! Thank you. Great answer. Very clear.

Comment: Welcome @MichaelGiovanniPumo. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this as select function:

```
var selected = items.filter(function(item, index) {
    var grab = 2;
    var skip = 2;
    var pos = index % (grab + skip);
    return pos<grab;
});
```

In this way you can decide how many elements grab and discard